Fantasy book with Red Monk antagonists 10+ years old
I know very, very little about this book, so I apologize in advance and appreciate any insight.
I read the book over 10 years ago, probably longer. It was a library book, if that helps. Fantasy series, but seems a bit more dark/adult than some with drugs/sex/violence being prominent.
The main elements I remember:

Multiple protagonists. One of them was a miner (probably) with yellow skin.
One of them was a badass warrior female.

A principle scene I remember was the badass warrior female had an epic, day-long fight with an enemy called a "Red Monk" who were known for fueling their power with rage and were considered unkillable. She was able to beat him because, "They're not actually good swordsmen."
I believe it was a part of a series, as the book did not have a solid ending. There were, I believe, two enemies seeking a character that the party MAY have traveled with (I forget) and they ultimately captured the character they wanted to.
If anyone has any ideas at all, that would be great.

This may be Dusk, first book of the Tales of Noreela series by Tim Lebbon.


Kosar the thief senses that Rafe Baburn is no ordinary boy. After witnessing a madman plunder Rafe's village and murder his parents, Kosar knows the boy needs his help. And now, for a reason he cannot fathom, others are seeking the boy's destruction.
Uncertain where to begin, Kosar turns to A'Meer, an ex-lover and Shantasi warrior whose people, unbeknownst to him, have been chosen to safeguard magic's return. A'Meer knows instantly that it is Rafe who bears this miracle of magic. Now Kosar and a band of unexpected allies embark on a battle to protect one special boy. For dark forces are closing in–including the Mages, who have been plotting their own triumphant return.

From this review:

-Fellowship: Also, there is a band (a.k.a. obligatory fellowship) of unlikely individuals with unique skill sets that resemble the expected motifs (thanks to Tolkien and Dungeons & Dragons): 1) vulnerable, naive farm boy; 2) a human thief; 3) a Shantasi warrior (read “Elf”); 4) a human witch; 5) a drug-addicted, miner (read “Dwarf”); and lastly another empathetic girl, a human scholar.

From this review, a description of the Red Monks:

There is an order known as Red Monks who kill anything that even vaguely resembles magic .... One other note- the concept of the Red Monks is truly original and interesting. They are human, but driven by rage and madness they are nearly superhuman. They fight through pain and fatal wounds and the only real way to destroy them is to either decapitate them or hack them apart. They are powerful and creepy. Well done! One of the cooler fantasy concepts in awhile.

A quote (found by DavidW) about the Red Monks not being good swordsmen:

"I had to use it all," she said. "We went with swords to begin with — a Monk's sword is as mad as the Monk. It's made of a metal that reacts with blood, craves it, whines as its being sated. Spooked the fuck out of me. We fought for an hour, and I put in some good hits. It's strange, but a Monk is actually a very poor swordsman. They're untrained, and madness doesn't aid coordination.

Found with a search for site:goodreads.com "red monks"

Beat me too it again, 'cause I went digging for quotes.  Here, you can do it: https://archive.org/details/dusk00lebb/page/128/mode/2up?q=swordsman

@DavidW: Hah. Thanks for the quote. I'd found one of the short story collections, but not that book yet.

Thank you so much! This is exactly correct. I've never used goodreads much and feel silly for not checking there, so I'll remember that for future searches.
I've been trying to find this book off and on for years, so thanks again!

@James: No worries. That "site:" keyword is really handy for finding books. :-D
